# Function only works with jquery 1.1.2 anyone know why?

Tags: jquery

hey guys, I am starting to get frustrated. I have a function I am using to fade a comment in after it is inserted. It works only with jquery 1.1.2 however, so none of the other functions on my page will work. If I try to use it with a newer version, comments will not show up since display is set to none in css so that comments can be faded. Does anyone know of a modification to make it work with jquery 1.3.2?

```
  function success(response, status)  { 
          if(status == 'success') {
            lastTime = response.time;
            $('#daddy-shoutbox-list').append(prepare(response));
            $('input[@name=message]').attr('value', '').focus();
            $('#list-'+count).fadeIn('slow');
            timeoutID = setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This: `$('input[@name=message]')`
Should be: `$('input[name=message]')`

Source: [jQuery 1.2 Release Notes](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2), under **Removed Functionality** - it still works on 1.2 (deprecated ), but was removed on [1.3](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3):

> The '@' in [@attr] has been removed. Deprecated since 1.2 this old syntax no longer works. Simply remove the @ to upgrade.

Comment: I really appreciate your help man, it works. This was the fastest response I have ever received, this site and it's community rocks.